# Change owner of volume mounted secret in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have my ssh private key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa) as a volume mounted secret in my container. Kubernetes seems to mount it with uid 0. However, my app runs as a specific user, and therefore can't access the ssh private key whose permission must be 600 at min. How can I change the ownership of my private key to reflect that of a specific user?

thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all? Is there something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, usernames are mapped to a user id which can be seen with the command `id -u someusername`.

SSH requires by default in many cases that your SSH key be owned by the user running SSH and be hidden to others `600`

Therefore, I highly recommend you copy your key instead of mounting it, unless your container user has the same user id as you.

---

If you are using a linux container, you can run the command inside the container to get the exact user id, and then chown your files with the user id instead of a user name.

`kubectl exec -it mypod bash` or `sh` if bash doesn't work
`$ id -u someuser`

OR

`kubectl exec -it mypod id -u` if your container has one user which started the main process

THEN

Copy your id file so you can chown it without interfering with your ability to ssh.

```
mkdir -p /data/secrets/myapp
cp /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa /data/secrets/myapp/id_rsa
chown $MYAPPUSERID:$MYAPPUSERID /data/secrets/myapp/id_rsa
chmod 600 /data/secrets/myapp/id_rsa
```

Because the host OS might have already mapped this user id, it may *seem* that your files are owned by another arbitrary user, but what ultimately matters is the user id of the owner/group.